# Changing objective C file extension from .m to .mm causes errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, protocols

Originally I had the file containing the warning below in LoginViewController.m, which I ignored. And the code works fine.

```
warning: sending 'LoginViewController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSStreamDelegate>'
```

But now I changed the file extention to .mm (LoginViewController.mm). Now I can no longer build the project, because of this error.

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<NSStreamDelegate>' with an lvalue of type 'LoginViewController *'
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
warning: sending 'LoginViewController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSStreamDelegate>'
```

This warning is due to the fact that you are not conforming to the protocol `NSStreamDelegate` when you are defining the class `LoginViewController`. Ideally your class should conform to that protocol so that when you are setting it to the delegate, it can understand that you are implementing any delegate methods which it expects.

for eg:-

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate> {}
```

Once you have fixed this, you shouldn't be getting the other error which comes when you change to .mm class.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has stricter typing rules than C. LoginViewController doesn't declare conformance to that protocol, so the pointer types are incompatible, which is a hard error in C++. Declaring conformance should solve it. (You'll still probably run into more type errors than before, as things that were silent conversions in C will require casts in C++.)

Comment: Not even that.  He just needs to conform to a protocol!

Comment: @CodaFi: Doh, you're right. I brilliantly skimmed over the actual details of the error and assumed it was the sort of thing I encounter most often in Objective-C++.

Comment: I can see that happening!  I know when I saw lvalue, the wheels started turning.